# Как определить когда нужно сканировать отпечаток пальца?

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Есть сканер отпечатка пальца [gtm-5110c31](http://www.holtek.com.tw/documents/10179/b198ecbe-64f7-4469-bcbe-d40d7ed1fd48). 
Для сканирования отпечатка, необходимо выполнить 3 функции:

- Включить подсветку - просто включает подсветку;
- Проверить что палец приложен - возвращает значение, приложен палец или нет;
- Сканировать отпечаток - сканирует отпечаток и сверяет его с БД.

Суть вопроса, можно ли включить подсветку и с помощью функции проверки что палец приложен ждать пальца, например если этот датчик будет использоваться в умном замке, то он может ждать десятки часов, в документации (приложена выше), ничего не нашёл про это.
Возможно кто-то уже работал с подобными модулями и знает?
Или нужно ставить дополнительный датчик приближения и только при приближении пальца включать подсветку и проверку?

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь, что здесь есть люди, которые работали с таким штуками. Но если Вы опишите, что может Ваш датчик, то скорее всего мы Вам поможем.

Comment: В идеале -- есть ли датчик света? Есть ли датчик прикосновения?

Comment: @hedgehogues, что именно вас интересует, что описать? Вы имеете ввиду датчик света встроенный в этот модуль(GTM-5110c31)?

Comment: Да... т.е. есть ли возможность каким бы то ни было, гипотетическим образом детектировать наличие предмета рядом (без прикосновения), а также само прикосновение?